# How to make this div full auto size?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a restaurant menu but I can't figure out how to do it I want to make the div named "menu-spacer" the maximum size it could get.

With the "min-width" and "max-width" it only takes the minimum width.

Render screenshot:
[image]

```html
    <div class="wrapper container w-50">
                <div class="wrapper menu block">
                    <div class="menu-content">Un menu tout à fait normal</div>
                    <div class="menu-spacer"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="price block">50€</div>
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper container w-50">
                <div class="wrapper menu block">
                    <div class="menu-content">Un menu</div>
                    <div class="menu-spacer"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="price block">50€</div>
            </div>
```

```css
    .wrapper {
        display: flex;
    }

    .menu-content{
        width: ;
    }

    .menu-spacer{
        width: max-content;
        border-bottom: green 2px dotted;
    }

    .menu {
        width: 80%;
        text-align: left;
        color: black;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
    }

    .price {
        width: min-content;
        text-align: right;
        color: black;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the secret here is knowing about `vw` and `vh` as you can research here:

[Viewport units: vw, vh, vmin, vmax](https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/)

See the fiddle: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lb98q7ac/)

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.menu-content {
  width: ;
}

.menu-spacer {
  width: 100vw;
  border-bottom: green 2px dotted;
}

.menu {
  width: 80%;
  text-align: left;
  color: black;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.price {
  width: min-content;
  text-align: right;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper container w-50">
  <div class="wrapper menu block">
    <div class="menu-content">Un menu tout à fait normal</div>
    <div class="menu-spacer"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="price block">50€</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper container w-50">
  <div class="wrapper menu block">
    <div class="menu-content">Un menu</div>
    <div class="menu-spacer"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="price block">50€</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried something like that but i don't want it to break the line like it does

Comment: How do you mean break the line? What happens that you don't want to? Let me know and I'll try to give you a better answer.